# How to set a view to the max bounds of the UIViewController in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, view, uikit

How do you set a button to fit the entire view frame, without using coordinates and height/width. I wanted to know if theres a way to set it to max frame.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You may use Auto-layout. Constrain the four edges of the button stick to the four edges of the root view. You can find many tutorials about auto-layout on the web. Just google them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to set a new button programmatically and set it's size to the full size of the screen you could do it this way:

Add the following code in your viewDidLoad():

```
  var button:UIButton!
  button = UIButton(frame: view.bounds)
  button.center = view.center
  button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
  view.addSubview(button)
```

This is the most basic way to add it, you still have to add code to account for when a user rotates the screen...

Remember there are other attributes in the UIButton object, which you can make use of like the label for example.

Cheers